# PhotoEditorSDK OrientationSensor error on Android 4.4 (API 19)

Tags: photoeditorsdk

I have a working application running on Android 6.0 (API 23), but when I try to run it on a Android 4.4 (API 19) I got an unexpected exception during PESDK.init.  Something should be missing in my project but I can not figure out what is going on...

The error is generated when trying to call initSensor method in OrientationSensor class as it is shown here :

```
import ly.img.android.ui.utilities.OrientationSensor;
public static final String VERSION_NAME = "4.1.4"
private static void init() {
    OrientationSensor.initSensor(PESDK.getAppContext());
}
```

The exception log message is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at ly.img.android.a.a(Unknown Source) 
at ly.img.android.PESDK.init(Unknown Source) 
at my.app.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:101) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ly.img.android.ui.utilities.OrientationSensor
at ly.img.android.PESDKInit.init(PESDKInit.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at ly.img.android.a.a(Unknown Source) 
at ly.img.android.PESDK.init(Unknown Source) 
 at my.app.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:101)
```

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be an issue with your "proguard-rules".
Please check your Settings, Orientation Sensor should not be removed by proguard because it clearly referenced in code.

Please also consider updating to v5.0.15